# Find and replace Notepad ++

Tags: replace, find, notepad++

I have a text file with some chunks of data that I want to remove/ replace. For instance I want to remove all chunks of customData. Is there a way to do this in notepad++? I know you can do something in the find and replace like customData(.....) but that only deletes the first 5 chars and I have a random amount between the curly brackets. Thanks

```
customData {
    blahblahblah
    blah{blah}
    randomblahblah{inside bracket blah}
    blahblah
}
```

Comment: What are you trying to replace with

Comment: notepad plus plus and replace it with nothing eg: remove it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a regex search to replace values between curly braces. The regex below may be suitable:

```
\\?\{([^{}]+)\}
```

Worked for your sample http://puu.sh/5fhpL.png

Comment: that works great! I am not familiar with regex so is there anyway I can include the "customData" part before the curly braces so I can replace that as well.

Comment: @fghajhe It will become much more complicated if you want to be able to nest braces as it quickly becomes non regular. Its possible to include new lines though

Comment: Just apply the regex I gave you twice (to n times) and it should work

Comment: (\{([^{}]|(?R))*\}) seems to get nested brackets. Now is there a way I can only replace customData{} and not all my {} eg "customData"+(\{([^{}]|(?R))*\})

Comment: Can the space be assumed before the braces or under what criteria should this match

Comment: the braces are on a new line eg: customData newline {}